# What franchises are these weapons from?

Tags: weapon, adventure-time, object-identification, art

The numbers refer to the weapon before them unless that weapon is last on the line.

(Also if anyone has a more complete screenshot of the remaining weapons or of ones with cut off portions please feel free to add, but keep in line with the number system, either through editing the picture or explicitly stating the order before the picture)

You can see a bit more of the top row [Here](http://jakewyattriot.tumblr.com/post/117179857618/bear1na-adventure-time-41-finn-by-jake-wyatt).

[image]

I'll kick off the party by naming

4 As a lightsaber

7 As a Klingon bat-leth

Comment: Looks like [this page](http://jakewyattriot.tumblr.com/post/117179857618/bear1na-adventure-time-41-finn-by-jake-wyatt) is the artist's tumblr where he posted the full image, you can see enough of the top row of swords to identify them.

Comment: Ahh sweet man! Thanks! @Hypnosifl

Comment: Since I missed the boat and the question has already been answered, I'll just say they missed the boat by not having Inigo's sword.

Comment: I looked at this and immediately thought "Morrowind", then I remembered just how many mods I was playing with last time I played morrowind...

Comment: I've added in the top line. You might want to renumber them

Comment: Is that Peter Pan's sword (top-left, 2nd from left)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1) **Thundercats** (Lion-O's Sword of Omens)

2) **Zelda** (Link's Master Sword)

3) **Final Fantasy** (Buster Sword)

4) **Star Wars** (Jedi lightsaber)

5) **He-Man** (He-Man's sword from Hasbro toys / Filmation animated series)

6) **Necropolis** (The Third Sword — **thanks @Catija!**; see image below)

7) **Star Trek** (Klingon bat'leth)

8) **Adventure Time** (One of Finn's swords, "Dual Sword" — they actually come in a pair)

9) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Scarlet")

10) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Root Sword")

11) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Demon Blood Sword")

12) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Pink Jewel Sword")

13) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Steel Sword")

14) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "Sword of the Dead")

15) **Adventure Time** (Another of Finn's swords, "CG Sword")

**Unnumbered swords (top-most row, partially obscured):**

- Very top right corner: Finn's "Dungeon Sword"
- To the left of the dungeon sword: Finn's "Arm Sword"
- To the left of the shark sword: Finn's "Lightning Sword"
- The two to the left of the lightning sword: Finn's pair of wakizashi swords
- The two to the left of the wakizashis: Finn's pair of "City of Thieves" sais
- The one to the left of the sais: Finn's "Crystal Sword"

---

Very special thanks to @Catija for locating sword 6.  Here is a supporting image for that one:

[image]

Comment: I didn't add Finn's sword to my question because I was hoping it had some history I was unaware of :(

Comment: #6 is the "Third Sword" from a webcomic called "Necropolis". http://jakewyattriot.tumblr.com/post/63686128382/necropolis-chapter-one-page-one-by-jake-wyatt See chapter 1 page 1

Comment: @Catija : Great find!  I'll add this --- credit to you, of course. :-)

Comment: #5 reminded me of [Frostmourne](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Frostmourne), but it's a bit too long and not quite ornate enough.

Answer (score 1):

Number 3 is Cloud's sword from Final Fantasy 7

Comment: Yep, I have that one in my answer.  Specifically, it's the Buster Sword.

Comment: Doh. @Praxis types faster than me ;)