# Why does Finn [from Adventure-Time] have so many swords?

Tags: weapon, adventure-time

Coming from [What franchises are these weapons from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108023/32946)

I can't help but wonder.. **Why does Finn have so many swords?**

Looking for the in-universe answer.

Comment: He's the last human in a world of crazy undead, giants, dragons, and demons. Why wouldn't he?
Also, he really only keeps one or two swords at a time; he never carries more than one and presumably vendors the items he upgrades over.

Comment: @Axelrod The image from the linked question suggests he hangs onto each of his swords, (*along with some from other franchises*). If the basis of the question is incorrect, (*He doesn't actually have so many swords*) - that could probably be an answer if it's expanded on a bit.

Comment: http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Finn's_swords seems to indicate that several of the swords have been broken, damaged, lost, or transformed throughout the series.

Comment: @SeanDuggan This also shows an abundance of swords he doesn't actively use, though. This is.. troublesome. He Goes around without a weapon when his choice sword is lost or broken, but he has a veritable armory in his house.

Comment: @Axelrod - Are you referring to a scene from the show when you say he has an armory including many swords at all times, or just to the image from the "What franchises are these weapons from" question? That image seems to be sort of satirical given all the swords from other franchises, and would presumably not be considered "canon" by most (though I don't know if *Adventure Time* has any official canon policy), I don't recall any scenes from the show itself indicating that he had a bunch of spare swords lying around for when his current sword gets broken/lost.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Go to the link Sean Duggan did.  Finn has swords lying around his house, in his horde (probably sold those ones), on his walls... he doesn't use them, though.

Comment: FOR ALL THE ADVENTURES, silly!

Comment: @Axelrod - Maybe the loot swords are too old and crusty to work well for adventuring? And Sean Duggan's link mentions some from the episode "slow love" which he apparently had lying around the house, one propped up next to his bed which falls over and slices it in two, and a pair of samurai swords...those could be loot swords too though.

Answer (score 3):

Most of Finn's swords come from looting and his various adventures. The tree fort has a whole room dedicated to treasures found from their adventures, it's not hard to imagine that they would find swords in any of the dungeons that they explored. The swords of most importance are the root sword which he found in the episode 'mystery train', the demon blood sword (a gift from his father, later destroyed) in the episode 'dad's dungeon', the grass sword 'blade of grass' (a replacement he brought when he lost the demon blood sword, later lost), and the finn sword first seen in the episode 'is that you?' (gifted to him on a quest). A full list of his swords can be found on the [wiki](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Finn's_swords)