# What franchises are these weapons and objects from?

Tags: weapon, object-identification

[image]

I think some have featured on a past post of mine ;)

Comment: OK now I'm curious- what is this image from? What spawned your question?

Comment: @fotijr just something I found online couldn't recognise them all so posted :) I'll put the link out tomorrow when I'm back at my pc

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108023/what-franchises-are-these-weapons-from

Comment: @N_Soong Captain America's shield was not obvious? o.O

Comment: I have this image framed in my home office! It includes the names of the weapons and the series they are from on the bottom.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. The [Tetriminos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) - Tetris
2. Power ring - *Green Lantern* (DC Comics)
3. The One Ring - *Lord of the Rings*
4. Pokeball - *Pokemon*
5. Batarang - *Batman* (DC Comics)
6. Noisy Cricket - *Men in Black*
7. Green Koopa shell - *Mario*
8. The Golden Gun - [*The Man with the Golden Gun*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071807)<sup>1</sup> (*James Bond* franchise)
9. Phaser pistol - *Star Trek: The Original Series*
10. Stereotypical cartoon bomb - Used *everywhere*. Could be from *Bomberman*, *Looney Tunes*, or [the 1966 *Batman* movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsJA1C19AyE)
11. Walther PPK, with silencer - *James Bond*
12. Dagger of Time - *Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time*
13. Machete - *Friday the Thirteenth* (confirmed from poster footer)
14. Freddy's glove - *A Nightmare on Elm Street*
15. Infinity Gauntlet - Marvel Comics
16. Kunai chain - *Mortal Kombat*
17. Bullwhip - *Indiana Jones*, most famously

    Also reminiscent of the Vampire Killer from *Castlevania*<sup>2</sup>
18. Plasma cutter - *Dead Space*
19. Twin Heckler & Koch USP Match pistols - *Lara Croft*
20. Crowbar - *Half Life*
21. Hammer - *Donkey Kong*
22. Dragon Dagger - *Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers*
23. Mjolnir - *Thor* (Marvel comics) or Norse mythology
24. Kung Lao's razor-rimmed hat - *Mortal Kombat*<sup>3</sup>
25. MA37 - *Halo*
26. [Captive bolt pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_bolt_pistol) - *No Country for Old Men*
27. (clockwise from top-left) Nunchaku, *bō*, katana, sai - *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*
28. Ryno V - *Ratchet & Clank: A Rift in Time*
29. Gravity Gun - *Half Life*
30. Luke's second lightsaber and Darth Vader's lightsaber - *Star Wars*
31. Cricket bat - *Shaun of the Dead* (confirmed from poster footer)
32. Unidentifiable wand - *Harry Potter*
33. Chainsaw - possibly from *Evil Dead*, *The Texas Chainsaw Massacre*, or every zombie *anything* known to man
34. Captain America's shield - *Captain America* (Marvel comics)
35. [Fusion swords](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Swords) - *Final Fantasy*, notably *Advent Children*<sup>4</sup>
36. Power Sword - *He-Man and the Masters of the Universe*
37. Sword of Omens - *Thundercats*
38. Excalibur - Arthurian myth. Although there are lots of different Excalibur designs, some variation of the one below turns up a *lot* when searching for Excalibur:

    [image]

    Although I'm not sure of the original source of this design, it's too similar for me to ignore
39. Aperture Science Handheld Portal Device - *Portal*
40. Master Sword - *Legend of Zelda*
41. Blades of Chaos - *God of War*
42. Proton pack - *Ghostbusters*
43. Mark 2 Lancer - *Gears of War*
44. Hylian Shield - *Legend of Zelda*
45. Katana - probably from *Kill Bill* (confirmed from poster footer)
46. Soul Edge - *SoulCalibur*
47. Gunblade - *Final Fantasy* (notably VIII)
48. BFG 9000 - *Doom: The Movie*<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Starring Christopher "Saruman" Lee

<sup>2</sup> Nod to Sean Middleditch for the suggestion

<sup>3</sup> Hat tip to CandiedMango for confirming

<sup>4</sup> Nod to Medinoc and Sabre for the lore tip

<sup>5</sup> Nod to congusbongus for noting that the BFG from the movie is different from the game

Comment: 17. I'd have guessed Vampire Killer from the Castlevania series; are there clues to indicate that it is much more likely to be Indiana Jones?

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch We've had some people cross-check my list against the footer of the actual poster, which lists the intended influences; none of them brought up *Castlevania*, so I'm fairly confident it was *intended* to be Indy's whip. Still, it's interesting so I added a note

Comment: 32's handle makes it Harry Potter's wand

Comment: How do you know 38 is Excalibur?  It looks like a fairly generic cruciform sword to me.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile See edit. Some variation on that design crops up a *lot* when searching for images of Excalibur

Answer (score 8):

**Jason Baker beat me to a complete list, so there's no point in finishing this one!**

Here we go...

1. Tetris blocks
2. Green Lantern Power Ring
3. The One Ring (should have got this one...thanks @N_Soong)
4. Pokémon sphere
5. Batarang (from Batman media)
6. Cricket gun (from *Men in Black*)
7. Turtle shell (Mario Bros.)
8. Golden gun (from *Man with the Golden Gun*)
9. Phaser (*Star Trek: TOS*)
10. ..
11. James Bond's Walther PPK
12. Dagger from *Prince of Persia*
13. Machete from *Machete*
14. Freddy Krueger's glove (*Nightmare on Elm Street*)
15. Infinity Gauntlet (Marvel Comics)
16. ..
17. Whip from *Indiana Jones* series
18. ..
19. Lara Croft's weapons of choice
20. ..
21. Donkey Kong mallot
22. ..
23. Thor's hammer Mjolnir
24. HAL-9000's eye (possibly, according to @WadCheber)
25. One of the primary Halo weapons
26. Anton Chigurh's pressurized air weapon from *No Country for Old Men*
27. Ninja Turtles' weapons
28. ..
29. ..
30. Light sabers (light and dark side)
31. Casey Jones' cricket bat (from *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*)
32. ..
33. ..
34. Captain America's shield
35. Buster sword (from *Final Fantasy*)
36. He-Man's sword
37. Lion-O's sword (*Thundercats*)
38. Excalibur
39. Portal gun
40. Master sword (from *Legend of Zelda*)
41. ..
42. Ghostbusters' proton pack

Comment: 24 = HAL 9000's eye

Answer (score 7):

1. Tetronimoes (Tetris)
2. Power Ring (Green Lantern)
3. The One Ring* (Lord of the Rings) *I assume. It's hard to make out
4. Pokeball (Pokemon)
5. Batarang (Batman)
6. Noisy Cricket (Men In Black)
7. Koopa Shell (Super Mario Brothers)
8. --
9. Phaser (Star Trek)
10. --
11. --
12. Dagger of Time (Prince of Persia)
    13.
13. Freddy Kreuger's Glove (Nightmare on Elm Street)
14. Infinity Gauntlet (Marvel Comics, Thanos)
15. --
16. Bullwhip (Indiana Jones)
17. --
18. --
19. --
20. Golden Hammer (Super Smash Brothers)
21. --
22. Mjolnir (Marvel Comics, Thor)
23. HAL 9000 (2001)
24. --
25. Captive Bolt Pistol (No Country For Old Men)
26. Sai, Nunchucks, Bo Staff, Katana (Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles)
27. --
28. --
29. Luke's Lightsaber, Anakin/Luke's Lightsaber (Star Wars)
30. --
31. --
32. Chainsaw (Evil Dead/Army of Darkness)
33. Captain America's Shield (Marvel Comics, Captain America)
34. Cloud's Buster Sword (Final Fantasy 7)
35. Power Sword (He-Man/Master of the Universe)
36. Sword of Omens (Thundercats)
37. --
38. Portal Gun (Portal)
39. Master Sword (Legend of Zelda)
40. Blades of Chaos (God of War)
41. Proton Pack (Ghostbusters)
42. --
43. Master Shield (Legend of Zelda)
44. Hattori Hanzo Sword (Kill Bill)
45. --
46. Squall Leonhart's Gunblade (Final Fantasy 8)
47. --

Comment: 24 = [HAL 9000](http://s3.amazonaws.com/stripgenerator/strip/88/39/34/00/00/full.png)

Comment: I like how you named the Tetris blocks, favourite part of all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty right. 33.) Chainsaw is definitely evil dead. You can see the severed hand socket on the end but Leatherface MUST BE repped (if Jason and Freddy are. Where's Mikey's butcher knife?). I think 44 could be alot of samurai sword weilding characters (tho Hanzo is most likely) kinda generic. Why Tetris blocks and pokeballs. A yo-yo is more of a weapon. (that was it's original purpose, lol...Google it) I do really like this however.