# Can you identify these Fantasy / Sci-Fi Weapons from Grrl Power?

Tags: weapon, object-identification, webcomics

Previously, I've been very iffy on these sorts of posts, but I figure it's worth a try. These images are from [Comic #408](http://grrlpowercomic.com/archives/2038) of *Grrl Power*. The author has stated:

> Most of these are pulled from comics, movies, etc where there is a definitive version to replicate here. Some of them are gimmies, but a few of them are from books that don’t have movie version yet.  So I used either a cover painting as reference or a replica someone made that features high on google image searches, so there’s some slipperiness there. Also, the two handed khopesh at the top is a sword of my own design for a character that might eventually show up in this comic or another one, in a fantasy universe where I have infinite time to draw (or at least write) multiple comics, so don’t kill yourself trying to ID it.

[image: Swords]

[image: Numbered Reference]

Comment: I'm not very well versed in comics or games, but even I know Cloud's buster sword (#13). Incidentally, when collected together like that, it's amazing how absurd the Rule Of Cool permits us to make weapons, and we just roll right along with it.

Comment: I recognize about a dozen of them, but I figured I'd make it fair game.

Comment: I've seen many of those, but I really suck on putting them into context :(

Comment: related: [What franchises are these weapons from?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108023/44383), [What franchises are those weapons from?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110540/44383)

Comment: Why is the top one "x" and grayed out?

Comment: @AidanO if you read the blockquote: because it is created by the artist who drew the image and thus is not a reference to an existing work

Comment: Ah, Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's create a community answer for this, even though I can only put a small amount into context:

1. Riddick's Ulak knives from The Chronicles of Riddick
2. Soul Edge from Soulcalibur
3. Scissor Sword from Kill la Kill
4. Ruby Rose's Crescent Rose
5. Alternate version of Stormbringer.  See #6 below
6. Elric of Melnibone's sword Stormbringer.  This is a close match of the official [(approved by Moorcock) Stormbringer replica.](http://www.raven-armoury.co.uk/stormbringer.html)  Since they are described as being almost identical, this could also be Mournblade, which was used by Elric's cousin Yyrkoon.
7. [Caber/glaive from Beastmaster](http://thedarkblade.com/wp-content/uploads/beastmaster-caber-glaive-300x212.jpg)
8. Triple Sword from The Sword and the Sorcerer
9. Excalibolg from Bludgeoning Angel Dokuro-Chan
10. Renji Abarai's Zabimaru from Bleach
11. Aragorn's sword Anduril
12. Jade Destiny from Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon
13. Cloud Strifes Buster sword from Final Fantasy
14. Sting from Lord of the Rings
15. Kratos's Blade of Chaos from God of War
16. Raiden Sword from Metal Gear Rising: Revengeance
17. Conan's Sword
18. Excalibur from Arthurian Legend
19. Lion-O's Sword of Omens from Thundercats
20. Link's Master Sword from the Zelda series
21. He-Man's Sword from Masters of the Universe
22. Dawnbreaker from Skyrim
23. Kandarian Dagger from Evil Dead
24. The [Sword of Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kahless), a Klingon bat'leth from Star Trek.

Comment: 23 looks like a wooden stake possibly from Buffy the Vampire Slayer.

Comment: @thing2k That was my first thought, but it looks more like a sharpened bone and Buffy normally just used wood.  I think you might be on the right track with vampires though.

Comment: Googling "sword with runes on the blade" turns up [this](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_Blade_(3.5e_Equipment)) for #6, but I'm not familiar enough with D&D to know if that is a standard thing or an artist's interpretation.

Comment: @djm I put Stormbringer on 6, as the pictures I found match it rather well, 5 seems to be something different

Comment: Well, if it's parallel, maybe Mournblade?

Comment: @Thomas From my googling #5 is a way better match for Stormbringer. Look at the handle. Also the blade is black. (See [this photo](http://images-cdn.moviepilot.com/image/upload/c_fill,h_600,w_800/t_mp_quality/is-it-time-for-elric-of-melnibone-to-hit-the-big-screen-stormbringer-jpeg-64340.jpg))

Comment: @Paul though here as number 1 looks exactly like 6: http://www.therobotsvoice.com/2011/07/14_famous_fantasy_swords.php

Comment: @Paul: Yes I was going to mention that 5 and 6 both look like Stormbringer. I went with 5 (and forgot to mention 6) because Stormbringer is described in the books as a black blade with red runes.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37464/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-can-you-identify-these-fantasy-sci-fi-weapons-f) for extended discussion.

Comment: Jade destiny? Don't you mean "Green Destiny"?

Answer (score 4):

24 is not just any old bat'leth; it's the [Sword of Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kahless).

Answer (score 1):

9. Excalibolg, from the anime "Club-to-death angel Dokuro chan".

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: You can always add it to the Community Wiki answer, although I can respect individual answers.

Comment: @randal'thor They where posted within seconds of each other.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Are we sure that #18 is Excalibur? From what source? The 1981 movie?

To me it looks like the hardcover illustration of "The Complete Book of Swords" by Fred Saberhagen. (Not the paperback versions; they are much fancier than the story says they are.)